# Choosing a motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, torque, vfd, pmsm

Long time listener, first time caller etc! Also, if you think this could be better answered somewhere else please let me know.

I'm building a pottery wheel at the moment and I'm in a bit of a quandary about motors. I'm looking for low speed (max 300 rpm) and high torque. Efficiency is also a consideration but I'm especially concerned with it operating smoothly at low speed. Due to the nature of the motors I would also like it to be direct drive. This also seems to be how the newer designs work.

I'm comfortable with the construction side and reasonably happy with the electronics but it really isn't my area. Unfortunately my research has finally reached the point where I'm just going round and round in circles so thought I'd reach out.

I have two similar motors available to me and I'm not sure which would give the best results. The first is a 230 VAC 3 phase, smart drive type motor from a washing machine.  I'm in the UK by the way. My understanding is it's a PMSM (I believe) and I would potentially be controlling it with a VFD.
It's similar to this [Washing machine motor](https://partstore.encompass.com/item/8174994/Samsung/DC96-01218E/)

The second is a 36V BLDC motor from an electric scooter that I would control with a cheaper DC speed controller after stepping down the voltage. It is similar to this [Scooter motor](https://images.app.goo.gl/oUAWXquM5Hs9bZDV8)

They're both reasonably low profile, which is great design wise, but more importantly, they're what I have available. I don't have a controller for either yet but having searched around it seems like a VFD would be somewhat more expensive. Not a problem necessarily, but a factor.

I was wondering what people's thoughts were? Just to recap, I'm particularly looking for smooth operation at low speed. Any help would be gratefully received.

Both motors are approx 400 W.

Comment: A PMSM *is* a BLDC; the only difference between these motors is the voltage they require out of the controller. BLDC is a misnomer, as the motor itself is actually AC; the controller acts as an inverter, converting DC to AC.

Comment: If you're wanting to mount a pottery wheel on the motor shaft, mechanical considerations are important. The scooter motor isn't designed to handle strong thrust loads or unbalanced loads. If the washing machine motor is designed to directly drive the tub (and I'm not sure, because I couldnt' open your link), then it's more likely to handle these situations. If you can safely deal with the 230 VAC wiring, it's probably better.

Comment: See comments on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67465/driving-permanent-magnet-dc-motor-via-pwm/67482#67482 . If you want a serious potter's wheel you need to get really serious about torque. Work out the torque you need and divide by your motor's torque constant to see the current you'll need. I'll be very surprised if a scooter motor can hack it.